# How get PHP fatal errors,warning error, notice error in json response

Tags: php, json

I am working on a restApi and i am using this api for my mobile and web development.which is build in PHP.i need my error in json format so that i can send this error in a proper response format to android developer and they can also easily handle it.so we will not face any crashing issue in our mobile app.

this is what i need exactly.

PHP ERROR:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'switch' (T_SWITCH) in
>   /var/www/html/phishem/index.php on line 68

What need:

> {error_code:"403",message:"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   'switch' (T_SWITCH) in /var/www/html/phishem/index.php on line 68"}

So how i convert this php error in json response.

Comment: Thats Error in your Php Code. Not an Error in Android

Comment: yes @TominB i know this. ultimately what i need. i need to send any proper json response to mobile application if any mysql error, php error , or any other error occurs in server side code.

Comment: use try catch and use json_encode for the error

Comment: but have to do it  in every methods. is there any setting in php configuration.that i can get error on a  file.like: how log files writes the error. how laravel and other MVC frameworks manage errors. can we do this manually.

Comment: A parse error means your code cannot compile. Accordingly, it doesn't run. The errors that report an unexpected [PHP keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) usually signals a missing semicolon (`;`) before the reported keyword. Fix the syntax errors. The errors, warnings and notices reported by the PHP interpreter are of no use to the Android front-end. They signal problems in the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

In api code you should haldle php warnings and errors, I don't think it is good programinig practice to handle php exceptions and errors in Front end(Android or IOS)

Comment: nope we are not handling error  mobile side. sometimes we faced the issue that if error in database query or whatever the type of error. obsly mobile application receive a bad json format. that time at least we can send a proper error message so that. we can save our app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of error is a **Server Side Error,** in which must be solve by handling the error instead of giving it as a *proper* response. Ideally, you must **handle/catch** all of the possible errors and give a proper response.

OR

You can also develop a **service layer** (also for a more secured architecture), that will pass through the request and response between the front-end side and the API side. In this case, you can parse a proper response message from the **service layer** if the server response is **500** which is **Internal Server Error** and return a JSON formatted message.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch fatal errors and output as JSON like this (in PHP):

```
function my_error_handler(){
    $error = error_get_last();
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($error);
}

register_shutdown_function('my_error_handler');
```

For non-fatal errors, you need to add this

```
set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
```

Additionally, you need to suppress the default error messaging:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

These will output the error as the following JSON

`{
  type : "8",
  "message" : "Undefined variable: a",
  "file" : "C:\WWW\index.php",
  "line" : "2"
}`